# Programatically acquiring svn rev with checked-out copies from new TortoiseSVN

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, revision

Previous versions of TortoiseSVN use the traditional `.svn` metadata folders, and those are needed for `svnversion` to work. It seems that the new version of TortoiseSVN doesn't use `.svn` at all - maybe it's using the registry, or something else. Anyway, now I can't use `svnversion`. The symptom is that it always says my checked-out folders have an "exported" revision. So I need to do one of the following:

- Tell TortoiseSVN to somehow use the old `.svn` behaviour.
- Find a new `svnversion` command-line client that understands whatever the new TortoiseSVN is doing.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the problem. I had been using SlikSVN's svnversion, but it stopped working. However, the new TortoiseSVN comes with its own set of command-line tools, and its svnversion works. I just had to squash the PATH to SlikSVN and uninstall it.

Comment: If you changed from 1.5 to 1.6, 1.6 to 1.7, etc., the difference in the working copy format is what made SlikSVN stop working.

Comment: Also, if you are using 1.7 (which is still only in Beta), TortoiseSVN is including the command line tools now since they are not available yet anywhere else in binary format. I would expect this makes it easier for users to test.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you upgrade one subversion tool, you should also get updates in your other tools to match (command line, AnkhSVN, etc.). In other words, if you update to TortoiseSVN 1.7, you will need to update your command line tools to 1.7. Otherwise the newer tools will update the working copy to the newer format and the older tolls will have problems.

Minor revision differences (1.6.**15** vs. 1.6.**12**) should not cause problems in general.